# load local HTML file when link is clicked in WebView

Tags: iphone, html, cocoa-touch, hyperlink, uiwebview

I have a WebView that loads a local HTML file like this:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test1" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

What I want is to click a link in the test1 local HTML file and then for the webView to load the test2 local HTML file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in a regular webpage. Let the link in test 1 point to test2.

Comment: can you tell me how I would write the <a href> link?

Comment: I got it using the answer above.

Comment: If my answer helped you, why is this one marked as accepted? You should mark the answer that solved the problem as accepted.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of loading a request, use the `- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL` method.

Create an `NSString` from the local HTML file like this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test1" ofType:@"html"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Then load it into the webview, like this:

```
[webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test1" ofType:@"html"]]];
```

Then in your HTML file when you link to other pages, just use their filename, like `<a href="test2.html">Test 2</a>` and it would load the page in the same webview without any issues.

Comment: You definitely got the right answer for loading local html file!  Thanks for the tips :)  I'll give u a +1

Comment: I get the following error if I use your code:"Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'NSURL *'" 

whats wrong?

Comment: My bad, I typed the code from memory, and either forgot that baseURL took an NSURL or forgot that pathForResource didn't return an NSURL. One of the two. Should be be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [webview loadHTMLString:[self htmlString] baseURL:[self baseURL]];
}
- (NSURL *)baseURL{
    NSString *htmlpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"webpage" ofType:@"html"];
    return [[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:htmlpath] autorelease];
}

- (NSString *)htmlString{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *html = [[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"webpage" ofType:@"html"] 
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                        error:&error] autorelease];
    return html;
}
```