# Local html file load in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a local html file in my xcode project. but i can't load that local html file with UIWebView.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code to achieve your request is:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 
self.view.frame.size.height,self.view.frame.size.width)];

NSString *indexPath = [NSBundle pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:indexPath]]];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this may it be useful to you happy coding :)
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147747/load-image-in-local-html-file-uiwebview) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214906/load-local-html-file-when-link-is-clicked-in-webview) [3](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=513586)